# Mouse and keyboard not working on Windows 8.1 after Ubuntu dual boot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

After dual booting my system with Ubuntu, my mouse and keyboard no longer work, in Windows 8.1. The light on the peripherals glows, so I know they are on, however they are just not responding. In the UEFI and Ubuntu however, they work just fine. I have to restart my computer though about 10 different times and eventually it will work, but then after another few restarts the mouse will stop working again. How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if every restart is just Windows-8 (not Ubuntu)?

Comment: I haven't gotten the chance to try that yet. But the first time it started working again I switched to ubuntu then back again and the mouse still worked and I restarted and went directly into windows and it worked. Then after switching back over to ubuntu the next day for a couple of hours it started again.

Comment: When you say started again, do you mean stopped working? Or continued to work properly? Both interpretations are possible.

Comment: I managed to fix it. Turns out some chipset drivers had gotten uninstalled. Also disabling XHCI and enabling EHCI allowed a temporary fix until next restart which then allowed me to go in and reinstall my chipset drivers.

Comment: Can you write up an answer. You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 years late to the game baby! I reinstalled some chipset drivers and disabled XHCI and enabled EHCI and that fixed it.

Comment: Can you tell us what drivers you reinstalled?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem after installing Ubuntu as a dual boot in a pre-existing Windows 7 computer. I solved it by going into the bios and setting "xHCI hand-off" to "enabled". That made my mice and keyboard work again.